# Using UNC name for local drives in Batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, local, unc, drive

I need to do copies/backups between a Windows XP computer, a Win 7 computer and several NAS drives using Batch files. I need to avoid using plain drive letters as there is a possibility a Batch file for one computer may be executed on the wrong computer and overwrite the wrong local drive.

```
xxcopy  "\\127.0.0.1\G$\sample\"    "\\NAS1\Volume_1\sample\"
```

will copy from the current machines G: drive to the NAS, but I want to be able to do

```
xxcopy  "\\Computer1\G$\sample\"    "\\NAS1\Volume_1\sample\"
```

or  even

```
xxcopy  "\\Computer1\G$\sample\"   "\\Computer2\G$\sample.copy\"
```

but when I use the computer name - I get 'Remote source not accessible'

Comment: `\\computer\shareName\path`

Comment: @MCND: He's already using double backslashes, but it was not visible due to formatting.

Comment: What is xxcopy? Is that a typo of `xcopy` or a special tool?

Comment: xxcopy is a third party tool - People comment that it is xcopy on steroids. It has a great many functions and has been around since before Robocopy IIRC.  http://www.xxcopy.com free for personal use

Comment: xxcopy is the only utility I could find that will correctly copy directory and sub-directory date/time stamps. Otherwise you end up with the current date. Too bad it's a command line utility with an insane number of switches, a gui would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%Computername%` variable for the local computer.

```
xxcopy  "\\%Computername%\G$\sample\"    "\\NAS1\Volume_1\sample\"
```

If you extract the `%Computername%` variables from all your machines then you can hard code them into your backups scripts.

Comment: That found the error- I added -- echo %Computername% to the batch file and found I had been using the Computer Description instead of the Full Computer Name. It looks like all will be fine now, thanks.